# How to POST large files with request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, async-await, fs

I have an app written in Electron and Node.js that takes a file and a description as inputs, and passes them off to a REST API.
It currently works just fine with smaller files, but anything close to 50 MB ends with an error `null`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  url: 'https://example.com/api/',
  formData: {
    formId: '1337',
    'answer.attachment.upload': fs.createReadStream('mybigfile.txt'),
    'answer.text': 'Some description of the file'
  },
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Should I somehow load the file into memory, and *then* POST it? Or how can I deal with larger files?

Comment: How is it failing? Not all servers will support such large files being uploaded.

Comment: Well, you hit the nail spot on. It seems the maximum file size is 30 MB. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Deadron led me to the right answer - the server wouldn't accept files larger than 30 MB.

Leaving the question up in case the code is relevant for anyone else.